# How do I recover my password in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

It never gave me the option to make a password, and now I can't even sign in. I've tried to click the link, but then it takes me to some website that doesn't help me at all!

How do I recover my password?

Comment: How did you make your original account?

Comment: Pokemon Go accounts are based on your Google account - do you remember which Google account you signed in with?

Comment: @TimMalone: not all are....

Answer (score 4):

If you've used a Google Account to sign-up, there's no password entry required on **Android** phones. (unless you have multiple Google Accounts attached to the phone, with password required on one of them.) On **iOS**, it's tied to a Google account as well, but you will need to sign-in with *{email address}* and *{password}*.

If you need to recover your **Google Account**, visit the following link: https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/

If you signed in with a **Pokemon Trainer Club** account, visit the following link to retreive/reset your password: https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-password

Comment: It asks for Google+ login on iOS I think. (seen on reddit - please consider verifying this if you will edit it in)

Comment: I'm going to see if I can find someone with an iOS version to check, but I believe you're right. Account ID tokens can be shared on an Android phone, but from my limited experience, iOS won't let one app authorize another.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. If you did not set a password, you probably signed in using your Google account.

**You actually have to click the word "Google" to sign in using your Google account.**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/192638)

Comment: @Dragonrage, this does actually give a possible answer, though it could be a bit more specific. Making an account through Google does not require a password. If a user is asked for a password, but had not set one, they would be using a Google account. This answer details how to sign into a google account, and does not mention passwords because there simply isn't one to recover, in the first place.

Comment: @Timelord64 hmm, yea I can see what you are saying. I think I misread the answer when I was reviewing it.